# How to create a fake event with faker dateTimeBetween?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, faker

I am trying to create a Factory in Laravel that will fake an event created on a calendar. The event has a **Start DateTime** and **End DateTime**. I want the start date to be sometime in the future from now and the end dateTime to be within a few hours of the start dateTime. I keep getting the same dateTime on both start and end.

I have tried a few different methods that I found from Google and they all result in both the start and end dateTimes being identical.

```php
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Event::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    $start_date = $faker->dateTimeBetween('+0 days', '+1 month');
    $end_date = $faker->dateTimeBetween($start_date, $start_date->modify('+5 hours'));

    $user = factory(App\User::class)->create();

    return [
        'name' => $faker->sentence,
        'description' => $faker->paragraph,
        'start_date_time' => $start_date,
        'end_date_time' => $end_date,
        'owner_id' => $user->id,
        ];
});
```

I expect the start DateTime to be between now and 1 month and,
I expect the end DateTime to be between the start dateTime and 5 hours later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is actually pretty straight forward to identify. You're using the same instance stored in `$start_date` in multiple places, which means that any change to that instance will be reflected in all places because:

> [In PHP objects are passed by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)

This means that if you create an instance of `DateTime` stored in `$start_date` and then you call `$start_date->modify()` that will modify the value and will be reflected in all places in which the variable is referenced.

So you're essentially passing the same two modified `$start_date` values to generate the `$end_date` value, which is why you get the same date for both range edges.

---

To fix the reference issue you should [create a clone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) of your `$start_date` and call `modify` on that to avoid modifying the original value:

```
$start_date = $faker->dateTimeBetween('+0 days', '+1 month');
$start_date_clone = clone $start_date;

$end_date = $faker->dateTimeBetween($start_date, $start_date_clone->modify('+5 hours'));
```

---

To mitigate the reference issues, PHP 5.5 introduced [`DateTimeImmutable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) which does not apply changes to itself. However, Faker's implementation of `dateTimeBetween` specifically checks if the instances passed to the method are of `DateTime` object (or just plain datetime strings that it can feed to `strtotime()`), so it doesn't work with `DateTimeImmutable`.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I had a feeling in the last 30 min while troubleshooting that it had something to do with the original `$start_date` being overwritten. This is what happens when I try to code with 2 hours of sleep. lol